# Como passar um algoritmo como parametro em java?

Tags: java, método

Tou a fazer algumas medições de tempos em algoritmos de ordenação e criei este método que calcula o tempo que um algoritmo demora a ordenar um array de números desordenados

```
public static double timeToSelectionSort(Double[] arrayOfNumbers) {

      double timeToSelectionSort =0;
  Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

  Selection.sort(arrayOfNumbers);

  timeToSelectionSort = stopwatch.elapsedTime(); 

  return   timeToSelectionSort;
  }
```

O problema é que tenho que criar este método para todos os algoritmos que quiser utilizar(mergesort,quicksort,insertionsort...)
Há alguma maneira de passar estes algoritmos como parametros em vez de estar a copiar este código sempre que quiser fazer testes para outro algoritmo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, você pode criar uma interface definindo um método "sort" por exemplo, e cada algoritmo vai implementar essa interface e definir o seu jeito de ordenar nesse método "sort" que você definiu na interface.

Feito isso, você vai rescrever seu método da seguinte maneira:

```
public static double timeToSelectionSort(SortInterface sorter, Double[] arrayOfNumbers) {
   double timeToSelectionSort =0;
   Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

   sorter.sort(arrayOfNumbers);

   timeToSelectionSort = stopwatch.elapsedTime(); 

   return timeToSelectionSort;
}
```

E suas classes que realizam esse sort podem ser como mostrado a seguir:

```
public class Mergesort implements SortInterface {}
public class Quicksort implements SortInterface {}
```

Nesse exemplo você estará usando bem o conceito de polimorfismo.

**UPDATE**

Usando a abordagem funcional, o mesmo resultado pode ser obtido da seguinte forma:

Aletrando a assinatura do método para recever um Consumer :

```
public static double timeToSelectionSort(Double[] arrayOfNumbers, Consumer<Double[]> consumer) {
```

E invocando o método apply da classe consumer da seguinte forma:

```
consumer.accept(arrayOfNumbers);
```

Deste jeito seu método final ficaria assim:

```
public static double timeToSelectionSort(Double[] arrayOfNumbers, Consumer<Double[]> consumer) {
    double timeToSelectionSort = 0;

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    consumer.accept(arrayOfNumbers);

    timeToSelectionSort = stopwatch.elapsedTime();

    return timeToSelectionSort;
}
```

Desta forma, basta que a assinatura dos seus métodos sort aceitem um array de double como parâmetro e eles estarão aptos a usar o seu método passando por exemplo:

```
timeToSelectionSort(arrayOfNumbers, Selection::sort);
```

Presumindo que a assinatura do método sort de Selection seja :

```
public class Selection {
    public static void sort(Double[] arrayOfNumbers) {}
}
```

Comment: Só que eu tenho uns 10 sorts para usar e cada um deles está numa classe própria. Não existe outra maneira? Não posso reescrever o meu método para usar o consumer?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Dê uma olhada!